# SilverStripe adding announcements / warnings to CMS pages

Tags: php, silverstripe

Is there a way to add announcement messages on top of admin pages, similar to the warning message on deleting the install files after a fresh SilverStripe install?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes - https://packagist.org/packages/sheadawson/silverstripe-timednotices

Though they'll appear where-ever you are in the CMS, not just on specific pages. You can choose a duration, and which users are targeted though.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, but comes pretty close!